# How i can read the first 10 lines and the last 10 line from filei in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, file

I have a file and it contain a thousands values so i wont to read only the first 10 and the last 10 values

So I used v.readline()
And v.read() but it didn’t give me the solution

Comment: You will have to clarify what you mean by ‘file.’ Are you refering to a txt file which contains lines of data? Or is it a csv, xls, PDF file? Or is this a long variable stored in a python script?

Comment: It’s a txt.file I’m trying to read from it

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the file using next function.

```
with open("file") as f:
    lines = [next(f) for x in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply printing:

```
res=[]
with open('filename.txt') as inf:
    for count, line in enumerate(inf, 1):
        res.append(str(count))
for r in range(10):
    print(res[r])
for r in range(count-10,count):
    print(res[r])
```

Alternatively, this saves the output as variable ‘result’:

```
res=[]
result=''
with open('filename.txt') as inf:
    for count, line in enumerate(inf, 1):
        res.append(str(count))
for r in range(10):
    result = result + '\n' + res[r]
for r in range(count-10,count):
    result = result + '\n' + res[r]
print(result)
```